# flutter ,error to convert "list" in "string"

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to convert a "list" in "string" from a external json file, but nothing happen in the virtual device ( i code with android studio).
The issue come from the "_MyHomePageState" class, moreover the "print" function return nothing too.
Thank you for your help.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//JSON
import 'dart:convert'; //(jsonDecode)
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //List<String> _items = [];
  List _items=[];
  String item;
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Json/test.json');
    final data = await jsonDecode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["items"];
      item = jsonEncode(_items);
    });
    print("item ::" + item);
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readJson();
  }
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        //child: Text(item == null ? '' : item),
        child: Text(item),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

test.json

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "p1",
            "name": "Item 1",
            "description": "Description 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "p2",
            "name": "Item 2",
            "description": "Description 2"
        },
        {
            "id": "p3",
            "name": "Item 3",
            "description": "Description 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to invoke the function called "readJson" in a stateful widget, you must add the function "initState" and there invoke that function to get it executed.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readJson();
}
```

Make sure that the path you use inside the function is the correct one to be able to read the json.

Comment: Thank you for your help , i tried this , but nothing more.

Comment: @igachi Can the function be executed? if you add a print to the beginning of the function?

Comment: thank you dude , your solution works well , my issue came from the virtual device (the hot reload have issue) . i updated the code